# GPU fans get really loud right before computer shuts off

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, shutdown, gpu

In the past two days, I've been getting this strange issue with my computer during shut down.

I would use my computer like normal without any issues, however, when I shut down the computer (Start>Power>Shut Down), the GPU fan will rev up and make a  loud noise for about 3 seconds before the computer shuts down completely.

The computer would start normally and run normally (it runs normally when I play games), it's only during the shut down process.

My Specs:

- OS: Windows 10 64bit
- GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 970
- CPU: Intel® Core™ i5-2500K
- Motherboard: [Asus P8P67](http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/P8P67_LE/specifications/)
- Memory: 20GB

**What's causing this issue and how could I fix it?**

Edit: My fans are quiet (normal) when booting up.  Only when shutting down will the fans go wild.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Computer Fans go to 100% when shut down](http://superuser.com/questions/297263/computer-fans-go-to-100-when-shut-down)

Comment: What changed two days ago?  Windows updates? Driver updates?  Try updating your video drivers to the latest offered by nVidia and see if that helps.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 nothing has changed, I didn't update anything.

Comment: Updating to the latest Nvidia driver solved whatever it was that's causing the issue.

Comment: If I were to make a wild guess, I would put money on your system being upgraded to Verson 1607 without your knowlege, the reason I say that is update does a literal upgrade to the OS.  Typically this would result in your display drivers being updated, and the fact installing the Nvidia drivers solved the issue, it sort indicates the incorrect drivers were installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating to the latest Nvidia driver solved whatever it was that's causing the issue.